# Helper class for Fragments management

Tags: java, android

A Helper class for Fragment Management.
The **FragmentsManager** class has methods to add and replace fragments.
The replace method checks if the given fragment is present in backstack or not and if the fragment is present it brings back the old fragment.
Need review for the following:

- Code optimized.
- Memory Efficiency
- Overall code review
- Can the replace method be improved in any way so as to avoid creation of additional fragments?
- I've tried to use popbackstack() but couldn't how to use it. Can you help with that?

Thanks

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

class FragmentsManager {

    private static final String TAG = "FragmentsManager";
    private static FragmentTransaction transaction;
//    Return Fragment Transaction
    private static FragmentTransaction getTransaction(Activity activity){
//        if (transaction == null) {
//            return transaction;
//        }
        return getFragmentManager(activity).beginTransaction();
    }
//    Return Fragment Manager
    private static FragmentManager getFragmentManager(Activity activity){
        return ((AppCompatActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager();
    }

    /**
     * Add Fragment to the given ID
     * @param activity
     * @param fragment
     * @param id
     * @param add_to_backstack
     */
    static void addFragment(Activity activity, Fragment fragment, int id, boolean add_to_backstack){
        transaction = getTransaction(activity);
        transaction.add(id,fragment,fragment.getClass().getName());
        if (add_to_backstack)
            transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
        transaction.commit();
    }


     static void replaceFragment(Activity activity, Fragment fragment, int id, boolean add_to_backstack) {
        Fragment check_Fragment = getFragmentManager(activity).findFragmentByTag(fragment.getClass().getName());
        if (check_Fragment == null) {
            transaction = getTransaction(activity)
                    .replace(id,fragment,fragment.getClass().getName());
            if (add_to_backstack)
                transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
            transaction.commit();
        }
        else{
            transaction = getTransaction(activity);
            transaction.replace(id,check_Fragment,check_Fragment.getClass().getName())
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your code looks **very good**, there are only **minor issues**:

## 1) naming

since you don't create any instances of `FragmentsManager` you should consider to rename it to `FragmentsUtility`. An Utility class provides **methods** to help you with your code while a Manager is an **instance** that does the work for you.

boolean should beginn with prefix *is* (or rarely as an alternative *has/can/should*) (in Java it's convention to use camelCase)
so rename your `boolean add_to_backstack` into `boolean isAddedToBackstack` rather (btw. in java it's convention to use camelCase)

## 2) comments

remove commented code!

## 3) javadoc

you provide some javadoc on the `addFragment` methode which is very crude - get things done and finish it!

the same applies to `replaceFragment`.

Comment: Thank you for your review. I thought JavaDocs should be provided for all the methods defined for description purposes. So I added them. Guess I was wrong. Thanks again.